# Passing parameter when calling webservices

Tags: web-services, windows-phone-7

How to pass param when calling web services?

My C# code is:

```
public partial class CityBlog : PhoneApplicationPage
{

     string str = "";
    public CityBlog()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        WebClient wc = new WebClient();
        wc.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("http://kcspl.in/nadalapp.asmx/GetCityBlog"));
        wc.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(wc_DownloadStringCompleted);
    }
    void wc_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
    {

        str = e.Result.Replace("</string>", "");
        str = str.Replace("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>", "");
        str = str.Replace("<string xmlns=\"http://tempuri.org/\">", "");

    }
```

See Uri statement above. That Uri is my web service link and `GetCityBlog` is my webservice class, but in this web service I want to add parameter like `id=1`. How can I add such parameters?

Answer (score 0):

You may add parameters either in the URL itself or as post parameters or as header information. Your web service should be equipped to read such information when it is pinged with such a request. You may search on Google regarding passing parameters to URL as GET, POST or HEADERS. Then you will find an easy approach. Hope this helps you in you task